# PHP rename function intermittently not working

Tags: php

I have an intermittent issue where PHP is issuing a warning that a temporary file does not exist, even directly after a filesize() on it.

```
$external_file = fopen($url, 'rb');
if ($external_file) {
    // store in a well-known location that won't get collected by system.
    $tmpfile = tempnam(__DIR__.'/cache/', 'test');
    $newfile = fopen($tmpfile, 'wb');

    if ($newfile) {
        while (!feof($external_file)) {
            fwrite($newfile, fread($external_file, 1024 * 64), 1024 * 64);
        }

        fclose($newfile);
        fclose($external_file);
    } else {
        throw new \Exception('Could not open file for writing');
    }
    if (filesize($tmpfile)) {
        // this sometimes throws a warning that $tmpfile doesn't exist
        // even through we just got the filesize for it.

        if (!rename($tmpfile, $filename)) {
            error_log('manual move try');
            // this is failing too.
            error_log(`mv {$tmpfile} {$filename}`);
        }

    }
}
```

Nothing really working consistently.  Failure rate is ~5%.  Since it is intermittent, we expect it is some kind of race state -- I even tried putting the rename into a while loop with a 10ms sleep @ 1000 iterations.  Just had 1000 warnings in my error_log.

As you can see above, even tried to bump out of PHP and shell it, with no success.

Have some more complex handling (moved here to simplify the main case) which hasn't worked either, like trying to force the file closed... but the file is pretty clearly closed.  This while loop doesn't run more than once, as far as I can tell without re-implementing and doing a trace.

```
        // have read that file handles are not released 
        // immediately sometimes.
        $iterations = 0;
        while (is_resource($newfile)) {
            if($iterations){
                usleep(10000);
            }
            if ($iterations > 1000) {
                error_log('MAXIMUM LOOP ITERATIONS.');
                break;
            }
            //Handle still open
            fclose($newfile);
            $iterations++;
            // 10ms isn't going to kill anyone.
        }
```

Have tried several other exotic things too, with no success.  Running on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Wild guess: have you tried clearstatcache() before calling filesize() ?

Comment: HI @JohnGreen, what is the value of $filename ? (random or fixed ?)

Answer (score 0):

If this script is executed concurrently, request A created `$tmpfile` is likely renamed by request B after `filesize` executed in request A. there are two solutions:

1. use `flock` to lock the `$tmpfile`
2. use random file name for `$tmpfile`

Comment: Its PHP.  Not sure I understand what you mean re concurrency.  That being said, `fclose` will release the `flock` (which doesn't appear to be the issue), and `$tmpfile` *is* a random filename (via `tempnam`).  Also -- fwiw, Ive certainly tried running the rename operation outside of the filesize operation.

Comment: I think they mean two instances of the script running concurrently, which could potentially generate the same "random" filename. If that is indeed the case, then you'll have to `flock($newfile, LOCK_EX)` after opening, to ensure another PHP process can't access it until it's closed. But you'll still have a problem: once you close it, it's now writable by another process just before you move it. In any case, why don't you just write directly to `$filename` rather than using an intermediary tempfile?

Comment: sorry, i just tested the `tempnam`  func, it never return  duplicate names ~~

Comment: @kmoser  Well, it was a random name.  But I doubled up on the random by generating a high-entropy uniqid.  That didn't solve the problem.   So, per your suggestion, I tried writing directly to the file (I wasn't before, because it was easier to clean up if there was a failure).  That didn't work, so I tried the flock on the direct file write.  Also, no good.

Comment: you can test same code on another server, maybe the problem is casued by the storage device

Comment: @JohnGreen So when you tried writing directly to the file, where did it fail? The call to `fopen()`? I have one more suggestion: Instead of `fopen()` and then `fwrite()` in a loop followed by `fclose()`, try storing the contents of `$external_file` in a buffer and then write it to `$filename` in an atomic operation via `file_put_contents($filename, $buffer, LOCK_EX)`. If that still doesn't work, I'd check if you're low on resources, e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105603/setting-ulimit-correctly-for-php-on-linux

Comment: There were multiple issues.  Issue #1 was that the library that generated filename was sometimes creating an incorrect one.  Realizing this and fixing it solved 99.5% of the error rate, however there is still an issue.  Not using file_put_contents, because the file is arbitrarily large (several gigabytes) and that would quickly exhaust PHP memory, even with very large amounts of RAM.  But since it is now a low rate and very hard to repro, I've left it for now, as it will generally get fixed and cached on a subsequent load.